# Struct and Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes

So in my code I have two structures. The first is a node which contains an int value and a pointer to another node. The second structure is used to create an array of 10 pointers each point to a another node. And it also contains link2 which will be used to traverse the array and all the nodes that it points to. I'm trying to add 3 nodes each holds the value 3 into the third index of the array. The pointer in the third index should point to the first 3 then that should point to the second three and so on. When I put add(a,3) three times and then print i get segmentation fault. I tried tracing the code but that still didn't make any sense to me because I always end up with three nodes. Can someone point me in some direction? Thanks!:)/>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    int x;
    struct node *link;
};

struct listofnodes
{
    struct node *alist[10];
    struct node *link2;
};

addFirst(struct listofnodes *a, int num)
{
    struct node *nodeone = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nodeone->x = num;
    a->alist[num] = nodeone;
    // printf("IT WENT THROUGH\n");
}

add(struct listofnodes *a, int num)
{
    struct node *current;
    current = a->alist[3];
    struct node *nodeone = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nodeone->x = num;
    current->x = 5;
    {
        while (a->alist[3] != NULL)
        {

            if (a->alist[3]->link == NULL)
            {
                a->alist[3]->link = nodeone;
                printf("IT WENT THROUGH\n");
                break;
            }
            a->alist[3] = a->alist[3]->link;
        }
    }
}


main(void)
{
    struct listofnodes *a =
        (struct listofnodes *)malloc(sizeof(struct listofnodes));
    // a->alist[3]=NULL;
    addFirst(a, 3);
    add(a, 3);
    add(a, 3);
    add(a, 5);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand..why do I need to return something?

Comment: Every time you create a `node` you aren't initializing the `link` value in the structure you created. So it's probably just something random rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Worse, you dereference indeterminate pointers in the `alist` member of `listofnodes` throughout this code.

Comment: I know that how i'm deferencing alist is the main issue here. I tried doing struct listofnodes *current = a->alist[3]; then changing all occurrences of a->alist[3] in add to current and that's worked. I just don't know why

Comment: The *main* issue here failure to initialize any of your pointers in the first place. There are other issues regarding memory management in general, but that is the first step you *have* to fix.

Comment: @user68212 is it clear why you have to pre-init your `link` members to `NULL` after you create your `nodes`? If you don't, your `add` function will think the `link` has a valid value (if it has some random value) and reference invalid memory.

Comment: [An example](http://ideone.com/m3ueAD) that is radically simplified. Take the time to look over each line. It still needs error checking, but it will make sense if you spend enough time on it.

Comment: Thank you so much for that sample code. It's gonna take me some time to go through it, double pointers and me don't get along..I'll post something right after I read it. Thans!:)

Answer (score 0):

In your main() function you have:

```
struct listofnodes *a =
    (struct listofnodes *)malloc(sizeof(struct listofnodes));
```

"a" is now a pointer to a listofnodes-sized block of memory containing random locations. You probably want to do something like

```
a->link2 = NULL;
```

Also, in your add() function, you have...

```
add(struct listofnodes *a, int num)
{
    struct node *current;
    current = a->alist[3];
    struct node *nodeone = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nodeone->x = num;
```

You have malloc()d random memory and put "num" into x, but you need to put a null into where 'link' goes, i.e.

```
    nodeone->link = NULL;
```

When you create the memory block using malloc(), you have to manually make sure the 'link' member is set to NULL - otherwise the number left there from last use will point who knows where...

Comment: you said 'a' is now two pointers? isn't it still one pointers that points to a huge block of memory that contains an array of pointers to node and link2?

Comment: I stand corrected, you are quite right. It's a pointer to the struct, which is a block of random data until you write to it.